# Microsoft OLEDB provider for ODBC 64 bit version on Windows Server 2012 for x64 CPU

Tags: vb6, odbc, oledb, ado

I have a VB6 legacy application that uses 32-bit ADO drivers to make a database connection using ODBC.

Now the customer has installed the 64-bit version of the database, and I am getting an error:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

I checked the net but could not find 64-bit OLEDB drivers for Windows Server 2012. There was a link for Windows Server 2003.

Can someone confirm whether the drivers exist and post the link to download them? Thanks.

EDIT 1:
This question is different from: [Migrating VB6 code to use 64-bit ODBC DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875522/migrating-vb6-code-to-use-64-bit-odbc-dsn)

This question is more about download the 64 bit ODBC driver, whereas that question is about code changes.

EDIT 2:
Even if I find 64-bit drivers, my VB6 application is 32-bit. Can a 32-bit application use 64-bit drivers at all? Note that installing the 32-bit version of database is ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

Your legacy VB6 application is a 32-bit OLE DB consumer. It therefore requires a [32-bit OLE DB Provider for ODBC Data Sources](http://uda.openlinksw.com/oledb-odbc-st/), and a [32-bit ODBC Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/), such as those from [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/) or various other sources.

The VB6 app loads some libraries into shared memory, and all of these much match bitness -- the VB6 app, the OLE DB Provider it loads, and in this case, the ODBC driver *that* loads, and in some cases, other libraries *that* loads.

Communications then happen over (typically) the TCP/IP stack or other networking layers -- which don't have to agree in bitness -- between the client-side libraries (i.e., ODBC driver) and the server-side (i.e., DBMS).

It does not matter that the target DBMS nor that the application's host OS is now 64-bit.

Comment: But the 3rd party database is now 64-bit, and they need to use the 64-bit version only for improved performance. So how will 32-bit drivers work at all?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: The coupling between a database server and its clients is very loose except in the case of embedded databases.  It is not occurring at a procedure call level but instead via some form of network IPC, e.g. TCP connections.  You don't need a 64-bit Telnet client to connect to a 64-bit Telnet server, right?

Comment: @TallTed, My scenario is that I need to use the 64-bit driver as this 64-bit database creates only 64-bit ODBC DSN and there is no way to create a 32-bit DSN. So basically you are confirming that my 32-bit VB6 app cant use  64-bit ODBC DSN. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm saying that your 32-bit VB6 app cannot connect directly to a 64-bit ODBC driver. You *can* use a Bridge Driver — in this case, I would say a [32-bit ODBC Driver for 64-bit ODBC Data Sources, such as from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/) — to achieve your goal.