# Migrating VB6 code to use 64-bit ODBC DSN

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I have a legacy VB6 application, which is making ODBC connections to a proprietory 3rd party database using ODBC.

```
Dim con As Object '  New ADODB.Connection
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open ("DB64bitDSN")
```

It used to work until now. Recently they have installed 64 bit version of the 3rd party database. The 3rd party database automatically creates a 64 bit ODBC DSN during installation, and the same is working when I connect using Excel's Data Connection Wizard, and using ODBC DSN as the data source.

But my code is giving error:

Error Description: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Error Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

How should I change my code to make it work? Do I need to add a reference to any library and modify my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the code. You need to ask "them" to create a 32-bit ODBC DSN. VB6 requires this in order to connect.

There is more information on [this Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx).

*Extract from the page*

> To manage a data source that connects to a 32-bit driver under 64-bit
>   platform, use c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

Comment: It is not possible to create a 32-bit ODBC DSN. As I mentioned, the 3rd party database is now 64-bit and automatically creates a 64 bit ODBC DSN during installation, and the same is working when I connect using Excel's Data Connection Wizard, and using ODBC DSN as the data source. When Excel can work using ODBC DSN, is it not possible for my VB6 code to work with minor changes?

Comment: Can a 32-bit driver work with a 64-bit database at all?

Comment: It should be able to.  For a client-server DBMS an ODBC Driver is really a "terminal" to the server, exchanging text or binary data formats across a TCP connection or other IPC mechanism such as DCOM, CORBA, Named Pipes, etc.  There isn't any close binding at a procedure call level at all.